# how to configure jersey providers in rest-assured

Tags: rest-assured

I have a webservice developed using jersey-api.

I'm using rest-assured to test the resources.When I run my testcase, I get the following exception.

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR T:[] V:[]  c.s.j.spi.container.ContainerRequest - A message body reader for Java class ... and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
```

I know that I need to configure my provider classes. I'm not sure how to configure the provider classes in rest-assured? I was not able to find any information about configuring jersey api "com.sun.jersey.config.property.classnames" in rest-assured.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I got it.Using the below code we can configure it.RestAssuredConfig.config().objectMapperConfig(
    new ObjectMapperConfig().jackson1ObjectMapperFactory(new Jackson1ObjectMapperFactory() {
     @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
     @Override
     public ObjectMapper create(Class cls, String charset) {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Comment: I think you should mark this question as solved